# How can I add FontAwesome "font images" to Popup menu in Extension Library in XPages

Tags: dojo, xpages, font-awesome, xpages-extlib

I am using the popup menu in Extension Library like this

```
 <xe:popupMenu id="pop">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:basicContainerNode image="/vwicn148.gif" label="Container">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Child" image="/vwicn148.gif"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes></xe:popupMenu>
```

And it look like this with an image added before the label

[image]

As my site is using only "font icons" from FontAwesome I want to display these instead of normal images. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options (and they are not pretty):

- use a custom renderer as Tim suggested
- subclass the control so label is rendered passthrou
- lobby the ExtLib team to add new properties
- use an XSP.OnLoad script to add the font awesom tags

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestions. What is custom renderer in this context?

Comment: It refers to the XPages Extensibility API concept of defining a Java class that will emit HTML markup that is representative of a given component's state. In this case, you would extend the default renderer class for the `popupMenu` component, ovverride the specific methods that you want to handle differently, register the new renderer, and set the `rendererType` property of your component instance to the ID of your custom alternative, either directly on the component instance or globally via a theme. At runtime your custom HTML will be sent instead of the default.